# Как добавить хинт к метке кластера

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

для добавления меток на карту использую json файл и такую конструкцию

```
objectManagerCL = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
    clusterize: true,
    gridSize: 32,
    clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
    clusterIconLayout: "islands#blueClusterIcons",
    clusterHintContent: "test"

});

objectManagerCL.clusters.options.set('zIndex', 1);
objectManagerCL.clusters.options.set('hasBalloon',     false);

objectManagerCL.clusters.options.set('hasHint'   ,      true);
objectManagerCL.clusters.hint.setData({hintContent:'test'});

myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManagerCL);
```

хочу добавить хинт к метке кластера, перепробовал разные варианты, но так и не понял, как это сделать.
хелп.

полного франкинштейна можно посмотреть по ссылке
https://vokrug-ladogi.ru/wp-content/plugins/metki-in-map/kartascript_json.js

Answer (score 0):

В документации API Яндекс.Карт есть один [пример использования](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Clusterer-docpage/#method_detail__createCluster).
Краткая запись без проверки условий примерно такая:

```
clusterer.createCluster = function (center, geoObjects) {
var clusterPlacemark = ymaps.Clusterer.prototype.createCluster.call(this, center, geoObjects);
clusterPlacemark.properties.set('hintContent', "Хинт кластера");
return clusterPlacemark;
}
```

На примерах из песочницы Яндекс этот метод работает — после добавления кода хинт появляется.

Comment: Как-то не понимаю, в какое место в ObjectManagerэто прописать. 
за основу я брал этот пример из песочницы
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager